# Passing extra data in startActivityForResult is received null in onActivityResult from another class

Tags: android, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I am new to Android development and I am working on a personal project which uses google map and image loading, among others.
I cannot figure out why, when using `startActivityForResult` combined with `onActivityResult` from 2 different classes of the same package it does not parse extra data inserted with `putExtra`

Code:

```
package com.example.gui;
class InitialMapLoad {
...
lGMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                final LatLng mClickPos = latLng;

                ImageView image = new ImageView(lActivity);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin_on_map);
                AlertDialog.Builder imgSelectPopup = new AlertDialog.Builder(lActivity);
                imgSelectPopup.setTitle(R.string.addImageCoords);
                imgSelectPopup.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelAction, null);
                imgSelectPopup.setPositiveButton(R.string.btnOpenGallery, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        pickPhoto.putExtra("gpsLng", String.valueOf(mClickPos.longitude));

                        lActivity.startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , LOAD_IMG_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
}
```

and the main activity class

```
package com.example.gui;

public class gui extends AppCompatActivity {
...
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        if (requestCode == LOAD_IMG_REQUEST) {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + selectedImage ); // this is OK
                    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + imageReturnedIntent.getStringExtra("gpsLng") ); // this is null
                }

        }
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments, the `getStringExtra("gpsLng")` is `null`.
Am I missing something? Is there another recommended way to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you are sending an intent to the system, `onActivityResult` does not guarantee those extras will be sent back the system.

Comment: I can see that, is there a guaranteed way that can be passed and received ?

Comment: No I guess, you need to change the approach on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I re-designed so it can work, thank you!